# Excel VBA - How to know if the next row or column is tha last one?

Tags: vba, excel, row

**Hello,**

What is the VBA code to know if the Excel's row or column is the last one? I mean if the cursor is in the 65,536's row and there is no more rows, how to know there will be know more rows? This can be easily done by a *if else* condition by entering the last row number (65,536). However, my VBA code to needs to work on Excel 2003-2013. The maximum rows numbers differ from different version.

My program will be entering data until the last row. If the next row is the last one, then how to detect it through VBA code? Also for last column?

Comment: You can test your position against `Rows.Count` and `Columns.Count` to check whether you ar going to exceed Excel's limits (for any version).

Comment: This [post](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastCell.aspx) answers a slightly different question but is helpful in understanding how to find the last cell in various scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this...

`MsgBox ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` 'It will give no of Rows of Active Sheet

`MsgBox ActiveSheet.Columns.Count`  ' It will give no of Columns of Active Sheet

`MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells.Count`  ' It will give Total no of Cells of Active Sheet

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer Chris. I had used Ctrl+k but, but I don't know why it was not formatted

Comment: Then don't use Total Cells code, I was just trying to make you know these are the ways to find number of rows, Columns and rows*columns=Total number of Cells.

Comment: @brettdj - I think it is good to have answers posted as such (even if they are short).